# symfony/maker-bundle won't install

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, bundle

I'm trying to install `symfony/maker-bundle` in a symfony project, so when I run the composer command `composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev` it give me this error :

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                                       
The "https://flex.symfony.com/versions.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution  
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

remove [--dev] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--no-update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] <packages> (<packages>)..
```

I tried to run composer clear-cach but it didn't fix the problem.

And knowing that I have run other `composer require` commands and it's worked.

PS: I'm running the project inside a docker

**- Edit -**

Running `composer update` give the same error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                      
  The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded:  


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

the container configuration :

```
[
    {
        "Id": "f827fe2e18129135992faf70763784002cb8999cc92328f8b8040ae6cd037ade",
        "Created": "2020-03-20T14:24:09.092197943Z",
        "Path": "docker-php-entrypoint",
        "Args": [
            "php-fpm"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 6145,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-03-22T14:33:13.557471161Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2020-03-21T18:29:19.303495154Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:9bac0ee874016fa916204ea165f7e29c149a1c74597055d401dd6e0c250ad273",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f827fe2e18129135992faf70763784002cb8999cc92328f8b8040ae6cd037ade/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f827fe2e18129135992faf70763784002cb8999cc92328f8b8040ae6cd037ade/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f827fe2e18129135992faf70763784002cb8999cc92328f8b8040ae6cd037ade/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f827fe2e18129135992faf70763784002cb8999cc92328f8b8040ae6cd037ade/f827fe2e18129135992faf70763784002cb8999cc92328f8b8040ae6cd037ade-json.log",
        "Name": "/sf4_php",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": [
            "4d45ed13e180c0ae0f2f2f0268cbeccb00a472ea6dff0a517843e386764d9e3e"
        ],
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/home/ahmed/Projects/TpsNorsys/tpSymfony/sf4:/home/wwwroot/sf4:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "sf4_default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Capabilities": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f28a9786ce1637d07f0234d11102183e78e7ae09deac2f67aad5d9fcec8dddd5-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8cd7eb4744b02cd270bec83915609eb7ceda1a1f9bf3453a6407ca2078c50245/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/da9338a79d1494a6808fc45efccdc40f5a110710100f26e04d0c28ffb385d8d1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6dd581054a3804af9b2e8f4124963e8d27178bd82ac7cb52d15e816e1a519eab/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5099df71809d3e315df1e6424aa69e7566d5e6496331b81eff7794e3a245e26f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4dffe9f1b9c50c0049eab252c6e07a35637fddaa09107601f112895dec4ec7d0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0202b42a297d92f2de064d27ae79fe8566d5eb0047dc5d29674bcfa2fab924b0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f806be8c15fa74bb8fb3bf46b152ca1db1e575253db15a2620fdd1ccabb33d19/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b6ee68333a10ba156ceefaf5f5f5e261da61d944c560d50e03193267185db1c1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a63cd3d5e4f283a14da1c62ae1850a9735ab576f9493c0d378a787c92ce3c336/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3e0a8c7b72fa1e3de02ee0e7d67386441747bfd73ba8cb3c80a5ddf92b9eb2f4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/546a1e0933af5c1c3cf3cc5501784e522e675dc45754aac433b3d48c904a31f4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/aa2f99b35f4196acde8dba58bb45b2257dbe7833fdd18e92197383df566a251e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e2d578ff092ca9a0b1b4f37a2d7cee463d5bea8ea4b0a55cb89fd3bce87574fc/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4f3b6db0adc93732202523abedd0a4b1e2e62c598785eaf84e774ad4f73d5b12/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c9ca4feb6ae9b92c2a4c13382ceac84eb75b6c1c9c4c7e3077ce09a10480c0d8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0c3444b73334cfdc360363086bad32aa633b52c41831c6ab0111bffa754fd229/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8623cb34d1637b5f43a0399b36e670140a0799193817041d009f06ca62a785de/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f8a8d2904d7fc3033a5467bc4df8f7c593b2b3b219d2c3edaf865b3839824298/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ee3d13ffaedff99be3b9a68eabd174b152cfcf878e4986f11d56056adae0e054/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c7db2ad01aff0f38a49a5cebaae72777c65e2590b796db8b1ca814fc0e634d87/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9414f1ba09db7eb4645272d4d1189bfc1e6624433a5ef8c104453a9fa4e3eefe/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/89603c46b73f688c2b20cfa9f5a7644efc8eef6b9546d0e64cb3edc6248a740f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/161fc8974c381f3175ca418cc04d386d2ab70092d012b161529621d91de25b53/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e7073b4edb75399abe5d2fb3056ee10e551f0bb1c9feff4f894f37d4c1bc6130/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3b9b5c3a35c08f6abf36c2dc3755200cae7b269c423d44f2d655fb7d04b3c93d/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f28a9786ce1637d07f0234d11102183e78e7ae09deac2f67aad5d9fcec8dddd5/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f28a9786ce1637d07f0234d11102183e78e7ae09deac2f67aad5d9fcec8dddd5/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f28a9786ce1637d07f0234d11102183e78e7ae09deac2f67aad5d9fcec8dddd5/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/ahmed/Projects/TpsNorsys/tpSymfony/sf4",
                "Destination": "/home/wwwroot/sf4",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "f827fe2e1812",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "9000/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "maildev_host=sf4_maildev",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tdpkg-dev \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkg-config \t\tre2c",
                "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
                "PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --disable-cgi",
                "PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2",
                "PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2",
                "PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -pie",
                "GPG_KEYS=1729F83938DA44E27BA0F4D3DBDB397470D12172 B1B44D8F021E4E2D6021E995DC9FF8D3EE5AF27F",
                "PHP_VERSION=7.2.10",
                "PHP_URL=https://secure.php.net/get/php-7.2.10.tar.xz/from/this/mirror",
                "PHP_ASC_URL=https://secure.php.net/get/php-7.2.10.tar.xz.asc/from/this/mirror",
                "PHP_SHA256=01c2154a3a8e3c0818acbdbc1a956832c828a0380ce6d1d14fea495ea21804f0",
                "PHP_MD5="
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "php-fpm"
            ],
            "Image": "sf4_php",
            "Volumes": {
                "/home/wwwroot/sf4": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/home/wwwroot",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-php-entrypoint"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "85aa961fd046f4d104106009169f60ebbdf1f55c7af362944c1fd490bf11df4a",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "sf4",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "php",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.21.0"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "43f1d9b03cd1624ded8c6e74f7535ed2879b040359b37fb2042fe9ba5daa71a2",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "9000/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/43f1d9b03cd1",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "sf4_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "f827fe2e1812",
                        "php"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "875e304c580d9a3fcefc07d9623089fcc68363c594f2fc90d407d918c9fc3aef",
                    "EndpointID": "b85a1286b191faed2b5bb3092d9a93c0875b2544d8071b12ea2e47be20e34eba",
                    "Gateway": "172.25.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.25.0.5",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:19:00:05",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I assume you meant composer require and not composer remove?  Sometimes the flex recipe server hiccups.  I just installed the maker bundle on a fresh project and it worked as expected.  Maybe try again.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's require, I will fix it, I was trying for a half day now, but I will try again

Comment: Still not working !

Comment: I think there's a network configuration error in your docker container. Can you check the network by doing a ping?

Comment: it's show's bash: ping: command not found,  it's a php container not an os, is there any other way to check the network ? I'm new in doker world :p

Comment: It's okay! I'm reading that you were able to install other packages and that is only this specific one the one that is giving you issues. Can you double check this with other packages? Every composer request should go against packagist so I find a bit weird this is the real issue and not a misscomprehension of the real issue.

Comment: Yep. We can confirm at this point that there's a configuration error on your container at this point.

Comment: Yeah I tried composer update nad also installing the profiler 'composer require --dev symfony/profiler-pack' and it give exaclty the same problem

Comment: So what I can do here ?

Comment: You should share your container configuration so we can find the error.

Comment: I added the configuration to the post.

Comment: It's fixed, I don't know why, but just after rebooting the computer and running the container it's worked !